# .replace(); multiple substitutions

Tags: javascript, replace

So I'm trying to replace any non-alphanumeric characters in a string, including spaces. I've found a solution that works, but it feels hacky. I shouldn't need two separate replace functions to accomplish this, but I can't figure out how to properly merge them. None of the documentation I find online addresses this.

```
str.replace(/\s/g,"").replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/g,"").toLowerCase();
```

Also, does the `^` character represent "not this" in this code? I found this as the proper way to remove non-alphanumeric characters repeatedly, but no one ever fully explains why this works. I'm guessing that `^` means to ignore the proceeding characters, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Yes the ^ inside square brackets means not. Unlike a ^ at the beginning of a line, where it means, "beginning of a line" :-( 
But perhaps "regex tutorial" is what you want to search for?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `RegExp` `/[^a-z\d]+|[\s]+/ig` which should replace all characters that are not word or digit characters

Comment: This is what I was looking for. I just need to separate what I want replaced with `|`

Answer (score 0):

You could omit the first replace and delete the allowed white space out of the character list for keeping this characters.

```js
console.log(' fßO oä '.replace(/[^0-9a-zA-Z]/g,"").toLowerCase());
```

Answer (score 0):

This one should work : `str.replace(/\W/g, "")` although it would keep the `_` character too.

Reference : https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_wordchar_non.asp

Hope this helps!